# Server selection timed out after 30000 ms Stack: MongooseServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am getting this error in my node application, I am using the following modules:
node: v14.16.1
mongoose: 5.12.3
mongodb: 4

**Also, When I restart my application it works fine for some time. I am attaching my mongo connection stats.**

Connection code:

````
        mongoose.connect("mongodb://username:password@ip:27017/dbname", {
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            autoIndex: true,
            autoCreate: true,
            auto_reconnect: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            socketTimeoutMS: 360000,
            connectTimeoutMS: 30000,
            poolSize: 50,
        })
        mongoose.connection.setMaxListeners(0)
        mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {
            resolve({ value: true })
        })
    })

**Error:**

Server selection timed out after 30000 ms Stack: MongooseServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 30000 ms
3|app  |     at Function.Model.$wrapCallback (/opt/deployment/production/dineout-feedback_13/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:5087:32)
3|app  |     at /opt/deployment/production/dineout-feedback_13/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:504:27
3|app  |     at promiseOrCallback (/opt/deployment/production/dineout-feedback_13/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:10:12)
3|app  |     at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/opt/deployment/production/dineout-feedback_13/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)
3|app  |     at model.Model.save (/opt/deployment/production/dineout-feedback_13/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:503:35)
3|app  |     at /opt/deployment/production/dineout-feedback_13/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3163:16
3|app  |     at /opt/deployment/production/dineout-feedback_13/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3193:7
3|app  |     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
3|app  |     at /opt/deployment/production/dineout-feedback_13/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3192:15
3|app  |     at /opt/deployment/production/dineout-feedback_13/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
3|app  |     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
3|app  |     at promiseOrCallback (/opt/deployment/production/dineout-feedback_13/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
3|app  |     at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/opt/deployment/production/dineout-feedback_13/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)
3|app  |     at Function.create (/opt/deployment/production/dineout-feedback_13/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3127:23)```

[![Connection stats][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EYVdA.png
````

Comment: you coldnt connect to mongo server , check two things 
1 - does mongo server bind on 0.0.0.0
2- does your mongoport 27017 is open 
and tell does mongosever installed on Linux  ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi Thanks for the quick response.

1. it is bind on private IP
2. yes, it installed on Linux VM
3. Port 27017 is open.

also, it works for sometime correctly.

Comment: could you telnet mongodb port from node js server ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi Yes, it connecting.

Comment: maybe it depends on security check , I think the best solution is creating ssh tunnel for mongodb port and in node js change the mongo uri IP to localhsot